# Retorno de data no DatePicker em outro formato

Tags: android, datepicker

Sou novo em desenvolvimento android, e tentei trabalhar com o datepicker para um trabalho, mas quando vou ver a data retornada é retornado assim:

Sun Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2020

Gostaria que ficasse 01/03/2020 para inserir no banco de dados e ficar mais facil o entendimento

O que poderia fazer?

Comment: Nunca trabalhei com DatePicker, mas dependendo do retorno é só usar `SimpleDateFormat` e passar pro estilo que você quer

Comment: Como você está a obter a data?

Comment: Como assim? Eu recebo dessa maneira: Sun Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2020
Mas queria receber apenas a data, tipo: 01/03/2020